# Squid3 cache limitation?

Tags: ubuntu, squid, ipv6

I'm using Squid3 for its caching capabilities on a bunch of IPv6 addresses. The only thing is, only 128 of them initialize properly, and any more won't connect.

Can you think of any settings that I can check?

From logs:

```
WARNING: You have too many 'http_port' lines
The limit is 128
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to bind to more than 128 interfaces? I'm curious to know what kind of application such configurations apply to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

squid/src/defines.h has:

```
#define MAXHTTPPORTS                    128
```

change that value. In ubuntu: get the source package, rebuild and install.

Answer (score -1):

In Squid 3.3.9 its

File: `src/anyp/PortCfg`

```
#define MAXTCPLISTENPORTS 128
```